# FireBug not working with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, firebug

I have started a new ASP.NET MVC project and have included the ExtJS library files. This all works fine when built from Visual Studio and i can display various ExtJS objects. The problem however is that FireBug has stopped showing errors in the Console, even when i type nonsense into the code block.

Setup is:

- VS 2008 SP1
- FireBug 1.4.2
- FireFox
  3.5.2

Firebug is working with other public web sites and when viewing other PHP based sites I'm developing.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks for any suggestions
Stuart

Comment: What happens if you pull up the firebug console and try to execute a command? Do you get a result/error?

Comment: When correct, commands execute correctly. When they are invalid they error as expected in the console.

Comment: Is firebug console logging enabled for this page?

Comment: Not really a .NET MVC issue since, if the HTML is rendered as expected (which you can show by adding a copy of the rendered HTML), then it's really a client-side issue. To help, please can you update the question with a copy of the *rendered source?

Comment: @Dan - see revised post below. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thought i would give some more info...

This is the code in the <head> tag of the Master page...

```
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/extJS/adapter/ext/ext-base.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/extJS/ext-all-debug.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/Modules/Portal/AdminMenuPanel.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/Modules/Portal/Portal.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        Ext.onReady(function(){
            Ext.QuickTips.init(); 

            ff //does not show errors with this here but works fine without it
            var e = new Ext.ux.AdminPortal();
        });
    </script>
```

EDIT - Rendered page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title>

</title><link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- ExtJS Library Files -->

    <link href="Content/Scripts/extJS/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Content/Scripts/extJS/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Scripts/extJS/ext-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="/Content/Scripts/Modules/Portal/AdminMenuPanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Scripts/Modules/Portal/Portal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        Ext.onReady(function(){
            Ext.QuickTips.init(); 
            ff
            var e = new Ext.ux.AdminPortal();
        });
    </script>



</head>

<body>





</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the suggestions so far!

Comment: Maybe that is because of your js files, in the past, when I was working with Ext JS, I had similar problems. Try to restart your browser and see if it works.

Comment: Ive restarted the browser but no luck. The thing is that the JS files appear to have loaded correctly - they can be viewed in the HTML tab of FireBug and correct ExtJS code functions fine.

Comment: Please can you update with what the rendered source looks like?